# mysql workbench connection type tcp/ip over ssh with libpam-google-authenticator enabled

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm attempting to connect to my MySQL Database using the Connection Method "Standard TCP/IP over SSH". I filled out all the SSH and MySQL connection details correctly, however I get the message: "Authentication error." because I'm protecting SSH with Two Form Factor Authenticator (libpam-google-authenticator). Is there another way to connect and resolve this issue?

Comment: I think we clarified that yesterday in the #workbench IRC channel: MySQL Workbench does not work with two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use Google Authenticator with mysql workbench, but you will need to change how SSH and Google Authenticator work together.  When you login via SSH, you probably enter your password and then you are prompted for your Two-Factor pin.  You want to change this so that you enter your password and pin, one directly after the other, on one line as the password:

[my-password][two-factor-pin]

This will work with MySQL Workbench TCP/IP over SSH.  I modify /etc/pam.d/sshd to use the forward_pass option for the Google Authenticator module.  You will need to put a line like this at the top of /etc/pam.d/sshd:

auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok forward_pass

Google Authenticator will authenticate the pin, strip it from the password, and pass the password along to the other PAM modules.

Answer (score 1):

Google Authenticator can be used with Workbench for two-factor authentication, but you will have to specify how SSH and Google Authenticator should handle the password and the pin.

When MFA using libpam-google-authenticator is enabled on Ubuntu user login over SSH most likely follows this sequence:

1. The user is prompted to enter their password
2. The user is prompted to enter their two-factor pin

Because Mysql Workbench only prompts once for SSH credentials the above sequence will not work, thus any attempt to login via Workbench will fail. This can be fixed by having the user enter their password and pin back to back on a single line like this:

[password][two-factor-pin]

**Install Google Authenticator**

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
```

**Create a custom PAM config file called “mfa-auth” using common-auth as a base**

```
sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/mfa-auth
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/mfa-auth
```

Add and/or modify mfa-auth to include these lines

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth required pam_permit.so try_first_pass
```

The try_first_pass option: “Before prompting the user for their password, the module first tries the previous stacked mofule’s password in case that satisfies the module as well”. From https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_unix

**Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd and add Google Authenticator**

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Add these lines to the top of the file

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok forward_pass
@include mfa-auth
```

Comment out line

```
@include common-auth
```

As we want to use mfa-auth to authenticate SSH connections now instead of common-auth.

**Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config to ensure SSH is using is using two-factor authentication**

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Set ChallengeResponseAuthentication to yes

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

**Restart SSH**

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

**Set up Google Authenticator pin for each user with your desired settings**

```
sudo su username
google-authenticator
```

Now when Workbench prompts for the SSH password users will need to enter their password and two-factor pin back to back with no spaces separating the password and the pin.

[password][two-factor-pin]

This new format will apply to any SSH connection.

See this post for further details and an example mfa-auth file: https://github.com/Katie-Shay/MFA-with-MySQL-Workbench